# what's the meaning of "Smash office hit"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I searched "Smash hit" meaning:

an unusually successful hit with widespread popularity and huge sales (especially a movie or play or recording or novel)

I'd seen a speech where they used "Smash office hit". I am not sure if it makes sense to add a noun word btw "smash hit". And what will it mean if it does make sense?

Comment: Smash *box* office hit. The box office is where tickets for movies are sold; hence a box office hit is a movie that sells a lot of tickets.

Comment: @LukeSawczak This phrase is found often and easily these days on "the internet" or by "googling". It's a misapprehension of the phrases _box office hit/smash_ and _smash hit_. As our language is increasingly spoken and read by speakers with no understanding or experience of the cultural underpinnings of terms like _box office_, it will probably attain an accepted status, eventually, like _" add in salt to injury"_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant A reminder that I should not rely on what's in my head but what's out there, particularly when the latter is virtually as easy to verify. Danke.

Answer (score 3):

The term *"box office"* refers to the office from which cinema (or theatre) tickets are purchased. A *box office smash* is a film or theatrical production that produces significant profit for the producers, and the term "smash hit" refers to the same thing.

The term *"smash office hit"* was coined either by a non-English speaker who was unfamiliar with the vernacular terms from which it was formed, or by an English speaker who had heard the terms but did not understand what they mean.

In any case, the term *"smash office hit"* is confusing, meaningless, and a kind of [*malapropism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism). Use the original *smash hit* or *box office smash* instead.

Comment: I'd seen it in a footage with subtitle (displaying "smash office hit"). it was spoken by a native speaker. That's why I had made extensive search for the phrase but no luck. so I try to ask here. it confused me too, a lot.

Comment: @dan Many native speakers are ignorant of their own language, and subtitles are often written by non-native speakers. What film was this?

Comment: it's a short movie in my handset, which tells people how to be successful in their lives. I did hear he said exactly "smash office hit"(which is the same as the subtitle displays). It has been translated into Chinese in that subtitle too. that Chinese translation told me "someone made great success as a white-collar worker (i guess that usually a white-collar worker works in the office)". I am not sure if "smash office hit" can be interpreted in this sense.

Comment: No, the phrase _smash office hit_ has nothing at all to do with working in an office as a white collar worker. As I said, there are many native English speakers who are ignorant of their own language. As for the Chinese translation, that has nothing to do with the meaning—or with anything at all, come to that. You will not learn English from subtitles, I promise you.

Comment: got it. appreciate your comprehensive response!